# Drupal Views - Missing [view_node] from rewrite tokens

Tags: views

I'm trying to follow along with this tutorial here but I don't see the [view_node] among my list of rewrite tokens.

[Tutorial Link](http://www.brightwebsitedesign.com/how-to-install-views-slideshow-module-on-drupal7)

I have rearranged the fields but I just don't have it available.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Make sure the field you wish you use as token is above the field you are editing. Also be aware that names might differ a bit depending on the field. Have you tried adding other fields to see they are appearing?

Comment: I did try rearranging the fields but made no difference.  I ended up finally finding a different tutorial that I was able to use.  For those interested, that tutorial is here:

[link]https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Frachel-prescott.com%2Fblog%2Fcreate-slideshow-overlay&ei=8v4AVY7KEciuggS5qoDoCQ&usg=AFQjCNExv5c5jkLr-1xf9LAGr_IfZm3tJg&sig2=noOtWZa-ISwLg8Zt4_7cvQ&bvm=bv.87920726,d.eXY